# Redirecting a redirect from batch to powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am using a batch file to write a Powershell script.  I understand that this is not the preferred method when the whole thing could just be written in Powershell, but here I am.

In the Powershell script there is a line that should redirect matching text to an output file.  However, since I am "writing" the Powershell script from a batch file, I am trying to redirect the line containing the redirect into the script.

Here is the sample code from the batch file:

```
Echo CLS >> Path\to\PowerShell\Script\example.ps1
Echo Echo "Please wait while we compare files" >> Path\to\PowerShell\Script\example.ps1
Echo Echo " " >> Path\to\PowerShell\Script\example.ps1
Echo $file1 = (Get-Content -Path Path\to\Footprint\File\footprint) >> Path\to\PowerShell\Script\example.ps1
Echo :sig ForEach ($Foot In $file1) >> Path\to\PowerShell\Script\example.ps1
Echo     { >> Path\to\PowerShell\Script\example.ps1
Echo         $Logfile = (Get-Content -Path Path\to\Log\File\Log.log) >> Path\to\PowerShell\Script\example.ps1
Echo         :log ForEach ($Line In $Logfile) >> Path\to\PowerShell\Script\example.ps1
Echo         { >> Path\to\PowerShell\Script\example.ps1
Echo          If (($Line -match $Foot)) >> Path\to\PowerShell\Script\example.ps1
Echo                 { >> Path\to\PowerShell\Script\example.ps1
Echo                     ECHO $Line >> Path\to\Output\File\Match.txt >> Path\to\PowerShell\Script\example.ps1
Echo                     ECHO "We have found a match!" >> Path\to\PowerShell\Script\example.ps1
Echo                     break log >> Path\to\PowerShell\Script\example.ps1
Echo                 } >> Path\to\PowerShell\Script\example.ps1
Echo         } >> Path\to\PowerShell\Script\example.ps1
Echo     } >> Path\to\PowerShell\Script\example.ps1
Echo Pause >> Path\to\PowerShell\Script\example.ps1
```

It breaks on this line:

```
Echo                     ECHO $Line >> Path\to\Output\File\Match.txt >> Path\to\PowerShell\Script\example.ps1
```

Here is the resulting Powershell script:

```
CLS 
Echo "Please wait while we compare files" 
Echo " " 
$file1 = (Get-Content -Path Path\to\Footprint\File\footprint) 
:sig ForEach ($Foot In $file1) 
    { 
        $Logfile = (Get-Content -Path Path\to\Log\File\Log.log) 
        :log ForEach ($Line In $Logfile) 
        { 
         If (($Line -match $Foot)) 
                { 
                    ECHO $Line 
                    ECHO "We have found a match" 
                    break log 
                } 
        } 
    } 
Pause
```

I have tried quoting that line with double and single quotes and have tried escaping the redirects, but no luck.  What am I missing?

Comment: You need to escape the internal redirection operators with carets, like this **`^>^>`**.

Comment: [not helpful comment] I always wonder why anyone does this or any instance where you're wrapping a batch around PowerShell. I literally cannot think of a use-case where it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cmd.exe` / batch files require that **shell metacharacters such as `>` - if used *outside of `"..."`*** (double-quoted strings) - be **individually `^`-escaped**.

<sup>Note: With `echo`, using double-quoting is not really an option, because the double quotes will be *retained in the output*.</sup>

Therefore, as [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) has already pointed out in a comment, you must use:

```
Echo                     ECHO $Line ^>^> Path\to\Output\File\Match.txt >> Path\to\PowerShell\Script\example.ps1
```

---

It's also worth pointing out that `echo`'s output will *include any whitespace before `>` or `>>`* in the redirected output.

For instance, `echo hi > test.txt` will write the string `hi`  - note the trailing space - to file `test.txt`